# Altering the order of custom fields in Standard Wiki

Tags: wiki-pages

I want to alter the order of the custom columns when in View Mode. Changing the order of the columns affect only in Edit Mode. How is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Enterprise Wiki or standard Wiki libraries in Collaboration sites?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in Sharepoint designer. open the list. Under Forms you will see the EditForm.aspx. This is where you will edit that view.

Comment: I appreciate the answer. However I am referring to the View Mode not the Edit Mode.

Comment: all of your views are in the location that I posted.